# How can I get Google Places API to work with a select/drop-down menu instead of radio buttons?

Tags: google-places-api

Currently I am using the regular radio button markup for the PlacesAPI but I would really like to use a drop down menu instead. Can someone give me any pointers as to how to get this working?

I have tried using the onChange event with a select tag but have not been able to get it working.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by"regular radio button markup"

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete)?